# How to assert at compile time, that a function is member of specific class

Tags: c++, assert

I have an interface in which the content of each function is created with a big macro. If a programmer is adding a new function, and forgets to add that function to the interface class, it creates many compile errors which distract from the actual error.

Would it be possible to assert at compile time, that a function that uses this particular macro is a member of specific class? C++03 or Boost features are available.

```
#define MACRO_OF_THE_DOOM(...) assertion_here(); do_something();

class A {
    void functionA();
    void functionB();
};

// This is valid usage
void A::functionA() {
    MACRO_OF_THE_DOOM(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}

// This should give an understandable compile error, which tells
// definition should be A::functionB()
void functionB() {
    MACRO_OF_THE_DOOM(6, 7, 8);
}
```

Comment: So the *real* reason for doing that is that you keep forgetting to prefix your functions with `A::` when implementing them? Have you tried `-Wall`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I think static assert would be better than `-Wall` in this case, because compile errors are shown before compiler warnings. I am also interested in whether this would be theoretically possible to do with a static assert.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Additionally, it seems that the compiler I use does not have warning for this kind of problem.

Comment: You are looking for something more sophisticated than `#define MAKRO_OF_DOOM(p1,p2,p3) /** in case of error: check that function is member of Foo **/  ((Foo*)this)->someOtherFun();` ?

Comment: @VolkerK Yes; in your example, the compile error would be shown at the line in which the macro is used. The programmer would never read the definition of the macro (and see the comment). Therefore it would be benefitial to have an understandable error message.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? see http://rextester.com/NKMW16046

Comment: @VolkerK Ah, I did not realize what error message that gives. A message about `functionB` not being a member function could be enough in my case. Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html)

```
#define MACRO_OF_THE_DOOM(...)  { assertion_here(); do_something(); }

assertion_here() { BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false); }
class A {
    assertion_here() { // no-op }
    void functionA();
    void functionB();
};
```

There are few caveats around this which could be worked around using type_traits but this solution may suffice for many cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to assert at compile time, that a function that uses this particular macro is a member of specific class?

If boost is available to you (I understand you cannot use c++11), then I suggest [TTI Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/tti/doc/html/index.html). Below is example with comments:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66a5016a1d02117c

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/tti/has_member_function.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(functionA)
BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(functionB)

class A {
public: // must be public for tti
    void functionA();
    //void functionB();
};    

int main()
{   
    // prints 1
    std::cout << has_member_function_functionA<
       A, // class type to check
       void,    // function return type
       boost::mpl::vector<> >::value // parameter list
       << std::endl;

    // Below generates no compile error - prints 0
    std::cout << has_member_function_functionB<
       A, // class type to check
       void,    // function return type
       boost::mpl::vector<> >::value // parameter list
       << std::endl;

    // Below static assertion, will fail at compile time    
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
        (has_member_function_functionB<A,void,boost::mpl::vector<> >::value));

}
```

I have updated to make it compliant with c++03, unfortunately static assertion without c++11 generates quite criptic message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:32:5: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
     ^
main.cpp:32:5: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
     ^
```